# Logback and Windows Event System integration

Tags: windows, events, logging, integration, logback

Has anyone integrated with success logback and the MS Windows built-in event logger? How can it be done?

It seems to me this is an important topic but I couldn't find any useful information regarding it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've blogged about my implementation of logback-ntlogger: http://ykchee.blogspot.com/2012/09/logback-nt-event-log-appender.html

Comment: hello, can you please provide some codes examples or a new link to the dropbox file from your blog cause its dead?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem to exist:
[switch from log4j to logback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011929/switch-from-log4j-to-logback)

However, as is noted in that link, you can just port Log4J's NTEventLogAppender and reuse the dll's that's packaged with it.

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/nt/NTEventLogAppender.html

Comment: Then post it as a project on GitHub and be a hero. ;)

Comment: Well guess that's an idea, thanks. At least we have the DLLs so we really need to write a new appender. I'm not putting your answer as accepted just because someone might come with a better idea :p

Comment: Definitely don't accept it yet; that's what we're all here for, to find out if there are better ideas.