# Logging in Windows Event Log using SLF4J and Logback

Tags: logging, log4j, logback, slf4j

Is there a way to log in to windows event log using SLF4J and Logback?

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945187/logback-and-windows-event-system-integration